# How do you get a Golang program to print the line number of the error it just called?

Tags: error-handling, go

I was trying to throw errors in my Golang program with `log.Fatal` but, `log.Fatal` does not also print the line where the `log.Fatal` was ran. Is there no way of getting access to the line number that called log.Fatal? i.e. is there a way to get the line number when throwing an error?

I was trying to google this but was unsure how. The best thing I could get was [printing the stack trace](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack), which I guess is good but might be a little too much. I also don't want to write `debug.PrintStack()` every time I need the line number, I am just surprised there isn't any built in function for this like `log.FatalStackTrace()` or something that isn't costume.

Also, the reason I do not want to make my own debugging/error handling stuff is because I don't want people to have to learn how to use my special costume handling code. I just want something standard where people can read my code later and be like

> "ah ok, so its throwing an error and doing X..."

The less people have to learn about my code the better :)

Comment: see http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go?s=4418:4472#L120

Comment: The moment you're printing line numbers it means I will have to dive into your code, so the "The less people have to learn about my code the better" is moot here. What you should do is have clear and concise errors.

Comment: @Wessie I disagree here. I read it as OP knows people will need to look at the code, but wants to minimise the amount of digging they have to do. Rather than following many levels deep trying to work out what some custom function does, OP wants an easy simple clear thing that returns line number so future readers don't have to try and work out what is happening there.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can set the Flags on either a custom Logger, or the default to include [`Llongfile` or `Lshortfile`](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants)

```
// to change the flags on the default logger
log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
```

Comment: So, for this to work I only need to set that at the top of one of the package files and it will available for all my files for that package?

Comment: Yes, if you're using a custom log you can use it like `var mylog = log.New(os.Stderr, "app: ", log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)`.

Comment: do I really have to create a variable? I can't just do log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile) at the top of my go file? I get an error: `expected declaration, found 'INDENT' log` when I try to do `log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)`. It just irritates me to have to create a variable for it, why can't there be a `log.Fatal("string", log.Flag)`. But creating a new variable log did work. Is it a standard thing to create log variables and stuff?

Comment: @Pinocchio: That error is because it's not valid Go, you can't have a bare function call at the top level. Put it in init() or some other entry-point.

Comment: you have to put it in `func init() {}`

Comment: Gives me `undefined log`

Answer (score 119):

Short version, <del>there's nothing directly built in</del>, however you can implement it with a minimal learning curve using [`runtime.Caller`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller)

```
func HandleError(err error) (b bool) {
    if err != nil {
        // notice that we're using 1, so it will actually log where
        // the error happened, 0 = this function, we don't want that.
        _, filename, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        log.Printf("[error] %s:%d %v", filename, line, err)
        b = true
    }
    return
}

//this logs the function name as well.
func FancyHandleError(err error) (b bool) {
    if err != nil {
        // notice that we're using 1, so it will actually log the where
        // the error happened, 0 = this function, we don't want that.
        pc, filename, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)

        log.Printf("[error] in %s[%s:%d] %v", runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), filename, line, err)
        b = true
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    if FancyHandleError(fmt.Errorf("it's the end of the world")) {
        log.Print("stuff")
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/uujg7Wr7zG)

Comment: While the answer already given fixes the problem neatly, your solution alerted me for the existence of something awesome — the runtime package! Lovely stuff :) https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/

Comment: The `fn` variable assigned from `runtime.Caller()` is actually the name of the file, not a function reference. I think of *fn* as function, not *filename*.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This is great example of `runtime` package usage. Very helpful for debugging through logs.

Comment: Awesome! This answer is a great explain why logger knows where it called.

Answer (score 7):

If you need exactly a stack trace, take a look at https://github.com/ztrue/tracerr

I created this package in order to have both stack trace and source fragments to be able to debug faster and log errors with much more details.

Here is a code example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/ztrue/tracerr"
)

func main() {
    if err := read(); err != nil {
        tracerr.PrintSourceColor(err)
    }
}

func read() error {
    return readNonExistent()
}

func readNonExistent() error {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/non_existent_file")
    // Add stack trace to existing error, no matter if it's nil.
    return tracerr.Wrap(err)
}
```

And here is the output:
[image: golang error stack trace]