# How to mark errors accurate to line with golang

Tags: go

I have seem this answer and use @OneOfOne answers.
[How do you get a Golang program to print the line number of the error it just called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809287/how-do-you-get-a-golang-program-to-print-the-line-number-of-the-error-it-just-ca)

But there is some questions.

```
func FancyHandleError(err error) (b bool) {
    if err != nil {
        pc, fn, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        log.Printf("[error] in %s[%s:%d] %v", runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), fn, line, err)
        b = true
    }
    return
}

func main(){
    FancyHandleError（funcA())
}

func funcA()error{
    err := funcB()
    return err
}

func funcB()error{
    err := funcC()
    return err
}

func funcC()error{
    err := errors.New("deep errors!!") //I want to get the location in here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    return err
}
```

It will print "**[error] in main.main[/root/temp/error.go:23]**"
That is in function main's line number.

But how to locate the error's line number in function C()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [runtime.Caller](https://godoc.org/runtime#Caller) which will give you all the details you need.

Your custom `NewError` function may look like this:

```
func NewError(message string) error {
    _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    return fmt.Errorf("[%s][%d] : %s" , file, line, message)
}
```

Here is play link for a sample [play](https://play.golang.org/p/XknlvmMqDF)

Comment: Here silimar to Log you can create a NewError function that appends the location to error string using `Caller`

Comment: updated the answer, check the `NewError`  function and the play link. This is the maximum one can do using the go libraries provided . The error interface only needs `Error` function to be defined so you can not find the location where error happened for external libraries unless they incorporate these details with error

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `log` package, you can instruct the `logger` to [prefix the entries with various information](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants).

```
log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
```