# Golang - how to get current running line in execution time

Tags: go

I would like to write a goroutine that tracks the execution point of the main routine. For example, for each line called in the main function, my goroutine would know that the execution is at that point. So at the end of the program, the output would be all the lines executed

Something like this:

```
func main() {
     go func() {
          // Get and print the running line
          // e.g: line 12 - fmt.Println("hello world")
     }()
     
     fmt.Println("hello world")
     time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

I took a look at the runtime pkg, but does not seem to have something nearly to what i want. Im not sure if it is possible as im dealing with a compiled language, but is there any other possible approach?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible - polling other goroutine activity is at the mercy of the scheduler & would most certainly miss "events". You could use external tools like [delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) as a step debugger.

Comment: Have you looked at the builtin execution tracer? https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-execution-tracer/

Comment: AFAIK fmt cannot do that, but log can. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24809859/18012302

Answer (score -1):

you can get line by

```
f *runtime.Frame
f.Line
```

and you have to import "runtime"